# Remap modifiers keys to press multiple modifiers at once

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping

I would like to remap a modifier key, in my case `CAPS_LOCK`, to send multiple modifiers at once on its one. By that, I mean not a specific combination of keys, like `<Ctrl>+C`. While the second part, mapping a key to a key combination, is answered in multiple questions, I have not found a solution for the first problem.

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/mapping-key-combination-with-xmodmap shows how to map to a specific key combinations
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap#Reassigning_modifiers_to_keys_on_your_keyboard Xmodmap, while able to create multiple layers for your keyboard, does not support this
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1764318 I have seen *AutoKey* mentioned a few times, but you cannot map to a modifier key
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/mapping-key-combination-with-xmodmap The proposed combination of `xbindkeys` and `xmacro` also does not seem to support this
- https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/ Xdotool seems promising, but the documentation is quite lacking

To make things more specific: I would like to remap `Caps_lock` to `Meta+Control+Alt+Shift` so I have a modifier key that does not conflict with any other key combinations defined by system applications. The combination is a result of sharing my PyCharm and Intellij keymap between a Mac and my Ubuntu machine and on Mac I use Karabiner to map the caps lock to a so called Hyper key, which is the combination of the above mentioned modifiers.

Comment: Sorry to ask, what exactly do you mean by "Meta": … Apple's command AND(OR) PC's windows-button ?

Comment: The Meta key is neither a Apple or Mac specific thing, but much older. In my case however, I mean the Apple command key.

Comment: After re-reading your question I must admit to have erred in what you really seek … While you mention in your last paragraph that you already use Karabiner to get a Hyper key, I doubt that I understand what (in your 1st paragraph) you call your "first problem". . . . What _EXACTLY_ do you need ?!? … and for what kind of system/computer? Your 5 examples sadly tend to confuse me rather than help …

Comment: What I really like to do is using multiple modifier keys by pressing just one physical key. Presing, in my case, the CAPS_LOCK key should result in four key down events (for CTRL, META, ALT and SHIFT).

Comment: Yes, but you wrote _"on Mac I use Karabiner to map the caps lock to a so called Hyper key, which is the combination of the above mentioned modifiers"_ and that's identical to `CTRL, META, ALT and SHIFT`, isn't it ?!? . . . I mean – _what's the difference?_

Comment: (Same comment as above:) … [– oder auch: hallo! … soweit ich verstanden habe, suchst Du genau den "hyper key", den Du am Mac sowieso schon benutzt? Oder willst Du _ZUSÄTZLICH_ dazu noch irgendeinen key drücken?]

Answer (score 1):

I realize this thread is old but for others like me who stumble by, this is how I've successfully mapped the caps lock key on my Apple Magic Keyboard to left-command+left-option+left-shift:

```
{
  "manipulators": [
    {
      "description": "Change caps_lock to command+option+shift.",
      "from": {
        "key_code": "caps_lock",
        "modifiers": {
          "optional": [
            "any"
            ]
          }
        },
      "to": [
        {
          "key_code": "left_shift",
          "modifiers": [
            "left_command",
            "left_alt"
            ]
          }
        ],
      "type": "basic"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -3):

[To prevent misunderstandings: do you mean *"at once on its **OWN**"*? You typed: *"on its **ONE**"*]

As its name insinuates, caps_lock ***LOCKS*** its state **permanently** (on my Windows keyboard).
MEANING: pressing caps_lock ***once*** returns "eventType: key_down" (in K-E's EventViewer) and only a ***second*** press will invoke "eventType: key_up".
So if you plan to "send" and be done with it, I'm afraid caps_lock prevents this "mechanically".

(This is confirmed/illustrated by: if you code an additional "to_if_held_down" with a long waiting time -2s- and press caps_lock shortly, your "held_down"-commands will *STILL* be executed after 2s.)

> **SO: if your Apple/internal keyboard behaves *DIFFERENTLY*: please comment *HERE* !!!**

*I am not sure* that I got the "intention" of your question (see comments) but I'll still try to answer.

The current version 12.1 necessitates manual editing of your `~/.config/karabiner/ karabiner.json` file for complex remaps (until a final "non-elements" version is released).
Following code works very well for me *in principle*, but its state ***is toggled*** key_down/_up:

```
{ "description": "META-Cmd & Shift & Control & Option",
 "manipulators": [
                 { "from": {
                            "key_code": "caps_lock",
                           "modifiers": {
                                "optional": [ "any" ] }
                            },
                     "to": [{
                            "key_code": "left_command",
                           "modifiers": [
                                 "left_shift",
                                 "left_control",
                                 "left_option"  ]
                            }],
                   "type":  "basic"
}               ]},
```

My Windows keyboard toggles *EVERY time* I press it, no matter what my settings in Sys-Prefs Keyboard Special-Keys are.  (I read [somewhere](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/issues/1253) that a Microsoft driver may be the cause.)